# Uploading Expo react native app to Testflight from Windows OS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, app-store-connect, testflight

I am new to react native and this is my first time trying to upload the app to Testflight. I have generated ipa file for my app and I am not sure how to upload it to Testflight from Windows OS. From the expo docs, I came to know that in order to upload the app to Testflight, one has to buy monthly package of EAS and I am wondering how all the people who developed expo app uploaded it to Testflight from Windows OS. Is paying for EAS service is the only way or are they any other way to upload it?

https://expo.io/pricing

Can anyone please enlighten me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple apps needs to be submitted from macOS. You can do this

- using EAS (it's uploaded from mac instances hosted by expo), there will be free tier in the future
- services like macstadium or macincloud that gives you macOS instance in a cloud
- fastlane + ci services like circle ci or github actions that supports macOS

Comment: Thank you @Wojciech Kozyra for answering. I am using EAS service but my build is failing with the error "add cache.key" in eas.json file. I tried adding it but still it fails. Do you have any idea about it?